# Hide Side Bar disabled

Tags: sublimetext

On macOS Finder, double-click a .sublime-text or .sublime-workspace file and a new ST window opens. But the menu item `Hide Side Bar` is disabled.

Wondering what's the story around this, why not show the side bar?

Seems need to `Show Open Files` first.

Comment: The side bar will only allow itself to be opened if 1) there is at least one folder open in the window, or 2) you turn on the option to show open files or 3) both of those things. If you are creating a window and you can't open the side bar without turning on that option, it's because the window has no folders open.

Comment: Got it! Wound it be possible to set `2) you turn on the option to show open file` to always true?

Comment: The setting is remembered in the current window, and will be inherited in any new windows that are created while that window is active. So, if you turn it on in all windows, it should persistently stay that way as you create new windows,